# Echo first three characters of filenames in CMD Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, filenames

`for /r %g in (*.html) do echo %~ng:~0,3%`

This does not work. I have tested a lot, but could not find the answer.

How do you echo the first three characters of all HTML-filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: first way:

FOR /r %%g IN (*.html) DO (
 SET "var=%%~ng"
 CALL ECHO %%var:~0,3%%
)

pause

:: second way:

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /r %%g IN (*.html) DO (
 SET "var=%%~ng"
 ECHO !var:~0,3!
)


GOTO :EOF
```

The fundamental issue is that substringing must be applied to an ordinary environment variable, not to a metavariable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

`for /r %g in (*.html) do ( set var=%~ng echo %var:~0,3% )` did it.